# textarea to expand by one line when text overflows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my text area to expand by one line only when the first line of text overflows. I don't want it to expand any further although it should allow to enter text in textarea.

I have overflow property set to hidden so that textarea appears like a input box to user.

how this can be achieved using jquery ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You want it to expand by one line if the first line overflows, and then stay at that size?

Comment: there are several plugins that do this...use one of them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hello**

you can use a plugin like this http://figovo.com/ or this http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/ or http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/4/autogrow-textarea-for-jeditable or many many more....

and then set a CSS rule on the textarea to set a max height like this --- `max-height: 150px;`

hope this helps